# In Java servlet how to dynamically get last update time?

Tags: java, servlets, timestamp

In my Java servlet I want to dynamically get the last update time of the file/app, therefore I don't have to manually update this info everytime I mke a change to the app, so I used the following line to get the info :

```
String executionDir=myClass.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString();
```

Then get the time stamp of the above "executionDir", it works fine on my local machine, it showed this : Last Updated : [ 2018-03-12 13:29 ]

I tested from my Netbeans, in one case it's Tomcat 7 which I downloaded and installed on my C: drive then pointed Netbeans to it. In the 2nd case Tomcat 8.5, which comes with Netbeans 8.2.

But when the app is deployed to 2 different tomcat servers, the info is missing, and showed this : Last Updated : [ ]

You can see the app live here : http://gatecybertech.net

Why ? How to get the timestamp correctly from the server ?

Comment: "It works fine on my local machine ..." Is this from your IDE or from a local Tomcat instance?

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: Thanks, just a few more questions for clarification. The local Tomcat container used by Netbeans, is it deploying the compiled app to webapps as a directory? E.g. if you look in tomcat/webapps, is your app a directory or a WAR/EAR file? Is your remote Tomcat behaving the same way? Also, what is the value of `executionDir` when it fails? Can you log this as well? I suspect that `executionDir` is returning a JAR URL, not a file URL, and so the timestamp can't be read directly.

Comment: On my local PC, I just checked, in "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps" it has nothing from my app, but in "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\webapps" it has both the .war file and a directory for my app. I think your suspicion is right, in that case, how to get the correct last update time value from my app without hard coding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some info related to my question at the following site, the answer is at the bottom : http://www.nakov.com/blog/2008/06/11/finding-the-directory-where-your-java-class-file-is-loaded-from/

Finally I used this line to get the time stamp :

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile()
```

Comment: Please [don't simply link to a resource which contains the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) ("barely more than a link to an external site"). Of course, you can cite the page, but then include what specifically from the link fixes the issue and put it in the context of the question.